# BrEng expressions to describe a man who is becoming stupid

Tags: expressions, idioms, british-english, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

I'm searching for British English expressions describing a person who starts to be stupid, crazy or foolish. I mean something like the idiom  *to lose one's head* and epithets like: *You fool*! Are there any where animals are used?

Comment: Animal related, 'muttonhead.'

Comment: Let's just check. Are you specifically asking for animal-related expressions *only*. Or do you want any expression at all?

Comment: _He's losing it._ _He's got a screw loose._  _She's off her rocker._  all common in UK amongst many others.

Comment: Round the bend.

Comment: *"Losing it"* is good to suggest the process of "becoming stupid". A current UK idiom is [**"She's lost the plot!"**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lose-the-plot)

Comment: One should probably distinguish between literally "becoming stupid" -- losing one's intelligence, presumably due to some medical condition -- and "going crazy" (either technically insane or behaving in some ridiculous fashion).  Most of the expressions proposed apply to the latter concept.

Answer (score 3):

For an emphasis on the *progression* of cognitive impairment, there are lots of "going" and "losing" phrases.

The most animal-related one I can think of that is used e.g. for the increasingly-senile elderly is to **go batty**. [Dictionaries seem split on this](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/batty): though the key element they all agree on is an aspect of mental instability or madness, several also include the notion that a batty person is *eccentric* or *unpleasant*, which seems important in the senses I've seen it used ("batty old cat lady", for instance). According to the [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/batty), the "bat" in "batty" doesn't actually refer to the flying noctural mammal, but to [a second sense of "bat"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bat#bat-2), an unattractive or unpleasant woman, that may be derived from French *bat* (prostitute) or perhaps from "battleaxe". Note that "batty" has a [completely different meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batty_boy) in Jamaican slang, related to backsides and hence to homosexuality.

**Go dolally** or indeed **doolally**, **doo-lally** or **doolali** is [from British Army slang for the Deolali sanatorium, Marashtra, India](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/161900.html). Originally an insane person was said to have the "dolally tap" (with various anglicisations of the place-name) but while I have often heard "go dolally" I have never heard the original "tap" form, which is certainly archaic. (The linked source says that even "go dolally" is archaic, but I have heard many older people use the phrase, and younger people seem to understand it.)

There is also **[go round the bend](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+round+the+bend)** for loss of sanity (from exasperation, intoxication or decrepitude) or, with more emphasis on eccentricity than insanity, **[go round the twist](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/round-the-twist)**. To **[go loopy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/loopy)** can capture the crazy eccentricity of "round the twist", or a sense of confusion and befuddlement.

**[Go off one's head/go out of one's head](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/off-one-s-head)** indicates that someone has become mad or demented ([and "off one's head" is often used for states of intoxication](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-off-your-head), e.g. "off his head on LSD"). There are related terms **go off one's rocker** or **off one's trolley** or **off one's nut** which, in my experience and from a few internet searches, are much more rarely associated with intoxication and more often to cognitive impairment from age.

We also have **losing it** and variants such as **losing the plot**, **losing one's mind**, **losing one's marbles**, **losing one's senses**. Note that "losing it" is very general, and often means losing one's temper or emotional control. But it can also refer to a reduction in aptitude or skill, which is useful if you want to emphasise the loss of *practical* intelligence: "[Tiger Woods has lost it](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/golf/10982369/Tiger-Woods-remains-the-most-fascinating-figure-in-golf-despite-his-six-year-quest-for-a-trophy.html)", for example.

Comment: The _doolally taps_ means [delerium tremens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delirium_tremens), and both forms are alive and well in my part of the world.

Answer (score 2):

If you need an animal involved:

1. Try *go cuckoo*. Or *go cuckoo in the head*.
2. Another one is *go batty*. See http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/bats-in-the-belfry.html for origins.
3. [*Bats in the belfry*](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/bats-in-the-belfry.html) as in "She's got bats in the belfry."
4. *[Squirrels in the attic](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=squirrels%20in%20the%20attic)*.
5. *[Mad as a March hare](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mad+as+a+March+hare)*.
6. [*Owls in the loft*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=owls%20in%20the%20loft).

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/batty suggests a different origin for batty, but "bats in the belfry" works as an answer in its own right even if not related to "batty" (I'm unsure which of our sources is correct: it seems quite possible to me that the "crazy" aspect of "batty" comes via "bats in the belfry")

Answer (score 1):

Loosing one's marbles.
Going crackers.

I can't think of an animal one right now, though I daresay there is!

Answer (score 1):

jackass

1.
a stupid person.

2.
a male ass or donkey.

https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=jackass+definition

Answer (score 0):

This one I copied from a text book lying near me which discusses about otherwise promising athletes who start to **lose their mojo** and then disappear into obscurity. I don't know if this is a bit extreme for you.

*According to merriam-webster:*

> Definition of mojo: a power that may seem magical and that allows someone to be very
>   effective, successful, etc

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mojo

Comment: +1  for at least getting the lose/loose distinction correct.

Comment: dear downvoter(s), it's a good practice to let someone know the reason why you think their answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [**go ape**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=bbcBCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=%22go+apeshit+to+lose+control;+to+go+crazy%22&source=bl&ots=PEwxxH-LaM&sig=hf74CnJ9RDS6s12bgnOOQ05bRoA&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMI2IPVhNS8yAIVTFoUCh2q8w8h#v=onepage&q=%22go%20apeshit%20to%20lose%20control%3B%20to%20go%20crazy%22&f=false).

> go ape: (*sl*) to go crazy ([**British Slang**](http://www.britishslang.co.uk/slang/go-ape))

Comment: "Go ape" is linked to "go apeshit", which, as far as I understand, doesn't mean to become stupid or go insane, but to suddenly become angry. I think that's different from what OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

**As mad as a hatter** is originally a British English expression, [Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/mad-as-a-hatter.html) says

> Mercury used to be used in the making of hats. This was known to have affected the nervous systems of hatters, causing them to tremble and appear insane. … Whilst not being the source of the phrase, we can't mention 'as mad as a hatter' and leave out Lewis Carroll. His 'Hatter' character from Alice's Adventures in Wonderland, 1865, is of course the best-known mad hatter of them all.  and he is portrayed as mad (along with all the other characters) by the Cheshire Cat:

I've always liked the silly expression ***[to be potty](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/potty)***. It is a quintessentially a British English term,  and means a person who is often so obsessed about a particular thing it makes them appear either eccentric, a buffoon or a lovable fool.

Answer (score 0):

Being called “[as dumb as a doornail/as dumb as a doorknob](http://lakesregionhome.com/blog/posts/2014/04/11/is-your-realtor-as-dumb-as-a-doorknob/)” originally meant that one was silent/unable to talk or make sounds, but like the meaning of “dumb,” the meaning of these two expressions has expanded to include “[being really] stupid” (from LakeRegionHome[dot]com, a Real Estate blog).
(The “doorknob” version might work better for “**becoming** stupid,” because you could easily (and almost cleverly) add “turning [as]” to it to hint at the “becoming” aspect: “s/he’s turning [as] dumb as a doorknob.”)

Although I'm not sure if this is used in British English, for an animal version of this expanded meaning of “as dumb as,” there’s “s/he’s [becoming] [as dumb as an ox](https://books.google.com/books?id=AokUAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA211&lpg=PA211&dq=%22dumb+as+an+ox%22+expression&source=bl&ots=-gnk1foe6W&sig=6SNOuiIcJ8FoVZXS6CFVfGUUu6s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDMQ6AEwA2oVChMIxrSw0ZG7yAIVShc-Ch2oHgUq#v=onepage&q=%22dumb%20as%20an%20ox%22%20expression&f=false)” or simply "You dumb ox,"
although I understand that oxen are actually quite intelligent.  (from “Ox-team Days on the Oregon Trail” taken from Google Books)

Answer (score 0):

My father used to frequently tell us (affectionately I'm sure!), 'you haven't got the wits you were born with!'.